# FB.AppRequest excludeIds doesn't appear to work Unity / iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have the Facebook Unity SDK integrated, logging on, and able to send requests via FB.AppRequest(). When I do so the friend selector dialog pops up as expected and I can parse the results of who was invited in the callback function nicely.

I've been over the documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Apprequest/

And the sample code in the SDK and here:
https://github.com/fbsamples/friendsmash-unity

but I can't seem to get the excludeIds field to work when popping the dialog up.

Here's the code I' using:

```
string excludeID1 = "123456789"; // Obviously I'm using real FB friend ids (non-dev accounts)
string excludeID2 = "987654321";
string[] excludeIDs = { excludeID1, excludeID2 };

FB.AppRequest(
    message: "This game is amazing! Check it out.",
    title: "Play this game with me!",
    excludeIds: excludeIDs,
    callback: AppRequestCallback
);

void AppRequestCallback( FBResult response )
{
    // Everything fine here, can parse selected/invited friend IDs, no errors reported
}
```

These 'excluded' friends still show up in the dialog though. Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the tags that you submitted it seems to me that you're testing your implementation on iOS. As mentioned on the Request Dialog documentation, the `excludeIds` and `filters` don't work on mobile yet. This feature is only available for the [Facebook site implementation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

I'll post again if we ever support this call for the Unity SDK.

Comment: Hey thanks for the information - I was looking at the documentation for the unity SDK here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Apprequest/ which doesn't mention that these parameters won't work on mobile, hence my confusion. If you could make it work in the Unity SDK that would be super-awesome by the way. Thanks again !

Comment: "... the excludeIds and filters don't work on mobile yet." I was wondering if there's an ETA for this feature?