# Alternative to excluded Ids in Facebook request dialog

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have been wrapping my head about inviting people on facebook using an android application with Graph 2.0 API. I could use the new invite API but my application does not have a canvas presence so I can't use it. So, I have built a simple system that keeps the ids that the user selects from the request dialog and compares them later against users that have installed my application (Using the /me/friends that now only returns users using your application). Everything works ok but the problem is that when user want to invite more friends through the request dialog I am not able to exclude ids previously invited or that were using my application previously. So all users are listed again in the request dialog.

I have been searching on stack overflow and found this: [FB.AppRequest excludeIds doesn't appear to work Unity / iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592010/fb-apprequest-excludeids-doesnt-appear-to-work-unity-ios) . This is exactly what is happening to me too.

So, is there any alternative way to do this? For example creating a custom dialog where I could filter user IDs and add to a custom request dialog myself?

Thanks in advance.